# Is it possible to read specific sections of an mp4 over a network?

Tags: python, html, video

Modern MP4 players let you jump to any position in a video without having to download the entire video

Here is an example video:
http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

You can track to any position before the video is downloaded.  I'm wondering if there is a python library that can read video from a position in the stream without having to download the whole video.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the particular format of the video stream, in particular the streaming format being used, but in general it is possible.

As an example, this is how bookmarks in video clients such as Netflix typically work.

The emerging industry standard for streaming, MPEG DASH, uses an index file or manifest with links to the individual streams that make up a video - i.e. video stream, audio, subtitle etc.

The streams are split into equal time length segments, for example 10 second chunks, and the player downloads them sequentially during normal playback. This allows the client to switch up or down to different bit rate versions of the video to match the prevailing network conditions.

Providing the stream supports it, it also allows the client to request a segment at a particular time offset - this is not always supported, as you can't request future segments for a live event, and some streams may also restrict availability of past segments depending on the content owners wishes.

Other streaming formats, HLS, Smooth Streaming etc have similar mechanisms.

If your mp4 is simply a static file hosted on a server, and is not using any adaptive streaming protocol, then so long as your server and client support byte range requests you can still request a particular chunk of the file. Most servers and client do support this these days, although you may need to explicitly configure your server to enable the functionality. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving.